# Saving and updating (SQL Server rows) using SubSonic 3.0 and LINQ

Tags: sql-server, linq, subsonic3, save

I feel foolish asking such a fundamental question but it would be more foolish not to ask :)

I have been using SubSonic 2.x for years and love it (Thanks Rob and co.).

I have started a pilot project using SubSonic 3.0.0.4 and have chosen the LINQ T4 Templates (excuse me if I have the terminology wrong).

Now I am new to LINQ but I am doing OK working out how to build the queries.

What I am REALLY struggling with is how to create and update data with the new toolkit.

Previously it was super simple where I could:

- 'new' an object if I didn't have one
- or Fetch or construct an existing one by id
- set some properties
- then 'Save()' it

Fantastic and saved me hours.

Now in the new toolkit some things seem to be the same like:

- creating an object
- setting some properties

but right now some things seem a lot harder like:

- Loading an object seems to be:

> ```
> db.Product.FirstOrDefault(x => ProductID.Id == 123);
> ```

- Inserting seems to be:

> ```
> db.Insert.Into<Northwind.Region>(
>          x => x.RegionID, 
>          x => x.RegionDescription)
>         .Values(6, "Hawaii").Execute();
> ```

- Updating an object seems even harder:

> ```
> db.Update<Product>()
>     .Set(x => x.UnitPrice == 100, x => x.ProductName == "Test")
>     .Where(x => x.ProductID == 1).Execute();
> ```

The documentation (http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Linq_Updates) talks about using the Repository but that just doesn't exist/get generated with the T4 templates I am using.

So any help to let me know that:

1. I have obviously set this up wrong
2. I have no idea what I am doing and the way to do it is ... insert answer here
3. I understand it correctly and should just suck it up

would be greatly appreciated.

If any more info is needed please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Mark

---- Update ----

To summarise the answer from Denis:

LINQ is a query language not an ORM

You can get to the Repository object via:

> var repo = new SubSonic.Repository.SubSonicRepository(db);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.. I migrated one of my projects to the SubSonic 3 too but frankly have not had any troubles saving the entities. I use the same ActiveRecord techniques and it still works great for me. For example, to retrieve an entity I am issuing:

```
var product = new Product(p => p.Id == 123);
```

For inserting:

```
var product = new Product();
product.RegionID          = 6;
product.RegionDescription = "Hawaii";
product.Save();
```

Updating:

```
product.UnitPrice   = 100;
product.ProductName = "Test";
product.Save();
```

As you can see you can still use the same `Save()` method.

So, not really sure why you try to do that through the 'db' context even though it can be used too :) Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks Denis from answering. I know I can keep the same behaviour if I keep using the ActiveRecord T4 templates. What I was trying to work out is why it seems like such a large step back when using the Linq templates. With the linq templates it is not as easy as your example above. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have clear answer.. but the docs also mentions that the SubSonic IS NOT AN ORM rather just a query tool that doesn't fully support object tracking like L2S, NHibernate, etc. probably that's why it has so tricky syntax for update operations. Also, regarding the lack of Repository implementation - I see it can be easily instantiated by calling var repo = new SubSonic.Repository.SubSonicRepository<Product>(db); and then use it throughout the code. Hope it helps somehow.

Comment: Hi Denis, I think your last line where you can create the repository is the silver bullet I was looking for. Thanks for that - the bounty is yours ;)